# App asks for login upon each launch after trying to restore products

Tags: ios, xcode, in-app-purchase

I keep getting an Alert upon launching my app asking for the login credentials for the sandbox test user. I believe this is caused by the fact that my `restoreCompletedTransactions` keeps failing, but I can't figure out how to fix it.

My `restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError` block is running successfully and says the error is "Cannot connect to itunes store".

Any idea why I am continuously asked to login after this failure?

Comment: Are you calling `finishTransaction:` upon completion of the purchase?

Comment: One possible situation is that you still have some transactions in the queue. You can check SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().transactions to see if there are some "dangling" transactions there.

Comment: Does calling `restoreCompletedTransactions` create a transaction? I'm confused because I don't know how to access a transaction if this is the case.

Comment: I have checked for additional transactions in my app delegate upon closing and opening the app but there are none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I have found the answer to my specific case of this problem, although there are some other fixes around the web that may work for other variations of this issue.

**After restoring purchases using a sandbox ID, you must validate the receipt each time you load the app, or else you will be prompted to sign in each time.**

In my specific case, I was not finished testing certain parts of my app, so I have commented out the receipt validation portion so that my products aren't loaded on purpose. After reading this suggestion online, I simply ran the app with receipt validation, logged in one more time, and boom, no more login window.